# Formulating Google Sheets Query for Two Sheets with Match in Multivalued Cell - getting error

Tags: google-sheets

This is what I have so far, I am getting stuck where I would usually do the IN syntax also AND with SQL WHERE

See the images for explanation of the following:
An example data for A in sheet1:

```
cell1 = [A,B,C]
cell2 = [A,B]
Cell3 = [A]
```

Sheet: OverallGroups

| Team | Projects | Bring |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A,B,C | Frying | [Oil](https://www.qfc.com/p/kroger-pure-vegetable-oil/0001111085605), [flour](https://www.qfc.com/p/king-arthur-flour-unbleached-all-purpose-flour/0007101201050?fulfillment=PICKUP&searchType=suggestions), [sugar](https://www.qfc.com/p/zulka-morena-pure-cane-sugar/0066144000021?fulfillment=PICKUP&searchType=default_search), [chicken](https://www.qfc.com/p/simple-truth-organic-air-chilled-boneless-skinless-chicken-breasts/0029082900000?fulfillment=PICKUP&searchType=default_search) |
| A, B | Baking | [Oil](https://www.qfc.com/p/kroger-pure-vegetable-oil/0001111085605), [flour](https://www.qfc.com/p/king-arthur-flour-unbleached-all-purpose-flour/0007101201050?fulfillment=PICKUP&searchType=suggestions), [sugar](https://www.qfc.com/p/zulka-morena-pure-cane-sugar/0066144000021?fulfillment=PICKUP&searchType=default_search) |
| A | Crafting | [Paper](https://www.hobbylobby.com/Art-Supplies/Painting-Canvas-Art-Surfaces/Construction-Paper/c/8-165-1292) |

Sheet: Jobs

| Team | Projects | Due | Bring (Return Query here) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | Frying | 1/2/14 |  |
| C | Frying | 1/3/14 |  |
| A | Frying | 1/4/14 |  |
| B | Baking | 1/5/14 |  |
| B | Baking | 1/6/14 |  |
| A | Crafting | 1/7/14 |  |
| A | Crafting | 1/8/14 |  |

The sheet2 "jobs" has in column A *just one letter* out of the potential lists in  cell1,2,3..., delimited by comma.

The format allowed the most condensed view of the jobs on the first sheet, then the jobs sheet expands them for specific when and where per project.

I know that is isn't conventional to have multivalued fields, but it was necessary to summarize the data view rather than have a flooded screen of replicates to manage missing elements in this school project.

An example problem:
I want to find WHERE TEAM A IN [A,B,C] exists in one instance and the related project from B in the query to explain what to bring to class. The selection returns one block of text content from C. And the condition that project matches the with the team letter.

```
=QUERY({OverallGroups'!A:C; Jobs'!A}, "Select C WHERE A matches '" & OverallGroups'!A:A & '" AND A matches " & Jobs'!A & "'")
```

I tried using
`&TEXTJOIN()` 
but this works for one to one cells, and won't parse the inner list by the comma.

------------- Part 2 need to copy the links by query 11/28/22--------

1. I have a query in Google Sheets which will search a template of materials to bring for another expanded sheet which has unique answers, but I need the links to appear as a result from this query

The difficulty is in being able to import multiple links per cell and groups to sort bringing materials for by the query.

The best snippet of code for this I have gets an error from another post: `=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(each,filter(OverallGroups!C:C,ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(OverallGroups!A:A,"(?i)"&each)),ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(OverallGroups!C:C,"(?i)"&OFFSET(each,0,1))))))`

"No matches are found in FILTER evaluation: #N/A"

This script on Google Sheets will provide the working data without hyperlinking...
`=query('OverallGroups'!A:C;"Select C where A contains '"&A2&"' and B contains '"&B2&"'")`

Please reference the data from these two tables to get the answer in the second table "what to bring" so that it references the links.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Sorry, this isn't very clear. Give better illustration of what you want as outcome and please use [Mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) instead of screen shots for your data (it's easy to do with that link).

Comment: Check the jobs sheet, all the data I want is there, in the Bring (Return Answer Here) column, that is where I want the code for the query to apply.

Comment: It works like a junction of two keys that returns an answer, match job classification with the job classification/group type, get the materials to bring to the job, like flour, etc.

Comment: Hello @JS_Drone, I'm sorry but it's not that clear. If all you want is to bring the project information, couldn't you just use a VLOOKUP? Or do you need to double check if the groups are into the assigned list for that project? Or would there be equally named projects assigned to different groups and different materials?

Comment: It looks like your solution would require I add another key table for expanding the list of groups rather than search using an "in" field clause of some sort that works in sheets. I'd rather avoid the redundancies, but that use of VLOOKUP could work.

Comment: The problem with expanding the projects into individual letters to lookup would result in splitting hairs for every project classification and team when they are overlapping one project, otherwise should there become another new discretely unique project that would be appended down the list, I respect the intent for unique fields and records for every project and associated group, but they are also containers for a specific project that could be expanded on into another jobs table with specific occurences when to bring the required materials. It complicates further the references to the jobs.

Comment: Something like: `=query('Overall Groups'!A:C;"Select C where A contains '"&A2&"' and B contains '"&B2&"'")` should do the job for one row, Let me know

Comment: Thanks Martin, you did awesome! This works!

The simplest way to put this concept is the larger group sheet acts as a template for what to bring or constructor for the expanded sheet which includes instances of it and may be customized. This works really well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is from Martín on this post (solved part I):

"Something like: `=query('OverallGroups'!A:C;"Select C where A contains '"&A2&"' and B contains '"&B2&"'")` should do the job for one row, Let me know"

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad it was useful! Here you have a multirow option:

```
=byrow(A2:A;lambda(each;if(each="";"";query('OverallGroups'!A:C;"Select C where A contains '"&each&"' and B contains '"&offset(each;0;1)&"'"))))
```

Comment: This one didn't work quite the same way, got #REF! Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in D3.


On another note, would it be possible to do the first and save hyperlinks if I add any in the templates to bring?

Comment: You have to delete the underneath cells, it expands automatically to the whole column. You can limit it to a certain range (ie: A2:A100) too. Didn't get your second question

Comment: Suppose the template for materials to bring list had hyperlinks to the specific brand, the query would return the format for the hyperlink to the expanded list. How would you do this? Because currently it would only return the text without links.

Comment: Then try with this: =BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(each,filter('OverallGroups'!C:C,ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH('OverallGroups'!A:A,each)),'OverallGroups'!C:C = OFFSET(each,0,1))))

Comment: I got this error after erasing the lower rows:
Error
No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.

Comment: =BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(each,filter('OverallGroups'!C:C,ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH('OverallGroups'!A:A,"(?i)"&each)),ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH('OverallGroups'!C:C,"(?i)"&OFFSET(each,0,1)))) Try with this if it is some case sensitivity or something like that

Comment: I got a parse error this time

Comment: Could you share a sample?, maybe start a new question and link it here

Comment: Hi Martin, I added a second part to my original post with sample data... When I made the edits for the tables.